# Pg-promise performance boost : ON CONFLICT

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, postgresql-9.5, pg-promise

I'm trying to follow the performance pattern recommended by the pg-promise library author [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Performance-Boost).

Basically Vitaly recommends to do so with inserts :

```
var users = [['John', 23], ['Mike', 30], ['David', 18]];

// We can use Inserts as an inline function also:

db.none('INSERT INTO Users(name, age) VALUES $1', Inserts('$1, $2', users))
    .then(data=> {
        // OK, all records have been inserted
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        // Error, no records inserted
    });
```

Using the following helper function :

```
function Inserts(template, data) {
    if (!(this instanceof Inserts)) {
        return new Inserts(template, data);
    }
    this._rawDBType = true;
    this.formatDBType = function () {
        return data.map(d=>'(' + pgp.as.format(template, d) + ')').join(',');
    };
}
```

My question is, how would you go when there is a contraint on the insert ?
My code :

```
db.tx(function (t) {
    return t.any("SELECT... ",[params])
        .then(function (data) {

          var requestParameters = [];

          async.each(data,function(entry){
            requestParameters.push(entry.application_id,entry.country_id,collectionId)
          });

          db.none(
            " INSERT INTO application_average_ranking (application_id,country_id,collection_id) VALUES ($1)" +
            " ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name" +
            " DO UPDATE SET country_id=$2,collection_id=$3",
            [Inserts('$1, $2, $3',requestParameters),entry.country_id,collectionId])

            .then(data=> {
              console.log('success');
            })
            .catch(error=> {
              console.log('insert error');
            });

        });

});
```

Obviously, I can't access the parameters because I'm out of the async loop.

I also tried to do something like this :

```
        db.none(
        " INSERT INTO application_average_ranking (application_id,country_id,collection_id) VALUES ($1)" +
        " ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name" +
        " DO UPDATE SET (application_id,country_id,collection_id) = $1",
        Inserts('$1, $2, $3',requestParameters));
```

But of course, it doesn't respect postgresql's standard.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote that example for [Performance Boost](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Performance-Boost) article to generate simple-form multi-inserts, nothing more, which was sufficient for the article.

What you are trying to do here is a bit more complex, and obviously `function Inserts(template, data)` doesn't have that kind of logic.

I can't tell you from the top of my head what would it take to change it to allow for your kind of scenario, but it can get quite complicated, and perhaps not even worth doing at all.

Luckily, you don't have to. I have been asked time and again for certain formatting helpers, which I released just recently - [helpers namespace](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/tree/master/lib/helpers). You need to update to the very latest version of the library (currently 4.1.9) to be able to use it the way you need.

Change your example to the following:

```
var h = pgp.helpers;
var cs = new h.ColumnSet(['?application_id', 'country_id', 'collection_id'],
    {table: 'application_average_ranking'});

db.tx(t => {
    return t.any("SELECT... ", [params])
        .then(function (data) {

            var insertData = data.map(d => {
                return {
                    application_id: d.application_id,
                    country_id: d.country_id,
                    collection_id: collectionId
                };
            });

            var updateData = {
                country_id: entry.country_id,
                collection_id: collectionId
            };

            var query = h.insert(insertData, cs) +
                " ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name DO UPDATE SET " +
                h.sets(updateData, cs);

            db.none(query)
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('success');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('insert error');
                });
        });
});
```

and that should do it.

See also: [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html).

Comment: I'm trying to run the code you provided, but as I have a lot more parameters, it crashes. I'll let you know when I succeed. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: Those helpers are very precise when it comes to generating valid queries. If one of them is throwing an error, there must be a reason. I've put details into each error, so you should be able to see what the issue really is ;)

Comment: Ahah yes I've seen that in your [code](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/lib/helpers/methods/insert.js) :-) I currently have the infamous "Invalid insert object at index 0" error. I'm checking why !

Comment: That only happens when you pass in an array of data with the very first element being not an object. All elements in an array must be objects in order for the method succeed.

Comment: @Stanislasdrg there has been a number of changes following the functionality you were looking for. Version 4.1.7 finalized it, and I updated the example accordingly.

Comment: Amazing development pace :-) Thanks for the notice, I'll look into it right away !

Comment: Your last edit works like a charm. Node's memory usage is hitting an all time low too. I really like the '?' character to mute parameters, it's an elegant solution and makes things much more readable.

Comment: There seems to be a "TypeError: Invalid parameter 'data' specified." at the h.sets(updateData,cs);  Is updateData supposed to be an Array of Objects or an Object of objects ?

Comment: @Stanislasdrg Neither. See [the API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.sets) - `A simple, non-null and non-array source object.`

Comment: Must be really tired, but I can't find a way to implement properly entry in "entry.country_id" . Entry originally came from a loop. That would require to put the updateData, query and request in an another loop ? But shouldn't insertData and updateData, respect the same order somehow ?

Comment: @Stanislasdrg I'm not really sure, if you change the logic like that. There must be an easy way, but it kind of makes it a separate question.

Comment: @Stanislasdrg I very much suggest upgrading to the latest [4.2.2](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.4.2.2), due to a bug fixed there.